# Is it possible Select Table to be used based on textbox, vb.net and MS Acess

Tags: database, vb.net, performance

Good day,

I am having issues on my vb.net form when it slows down when fetching data from MS Access Table with 30k data.

As a possible fix I was thinking that maybe it will be possible to only fetch data on the different table if it matches the textbox or text given. I am planning to sort out the data into category which will have 1 table per category.

Thank you.

This is what  I am using

```
 Private Sub txtProcYM_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtProcYM.Leave
    Dim lst As List(Of DataTable)
    Try
        lst = qtyCheck(txtLot.Text, txtPartNumber.Text, txtProcess1.Text, txtProcess2.Text, txtProcess3.Text, txtProcess4.Text, txtProcess5.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try

    proc1QTYIn.Text = lst(0)(0)(0).ToString
    proc1QTYOut.Text = lst(0)(0)(1).ToString
    proc2QTYIn.Text = lst(1)(0)(0).ToString
    proc2QTYOut.Text = lst(1)(0)(1).ToString
    proc3QTYIn.Text = lst(2)(0)(0).ToString
    proc3QTYOut.Text = lst(2)(0)(1).ToString
    proc4QTYIn.Text = lst(3)(0)(0).ToString
    proc4QTYOut.Text = lst(3)(0)(1).ToString
    proc5QTYIn.Text = lst(4)(0)(0).ToString
    proc5QTYOut.Text = lst(4)(0)(1).ToString


End Sub



Private Function qtyCheck(Lot As String, PartNum As String, Process1 As String, Process2 As String, Process3 As String, Process4 As String, Process5 As String) As List(Of DataTable)
    Dim constr As String = con.ConnectionString
    Dim query1 As String = "SELECT SUM(prdINPUT) AS prdInput,SUM(prdOUTPUT) AS prdOutput FROM ProdOutput_Lathe WHERE HELPER = @HELPER;"
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    Dim dt3 As New DataTable
    Dim dt4 As New DataTable
    Dim dt5 As New DataTable
    Dim lst As New List(Of DataTable)
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr),
        cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query1, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HELPER", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = $"{Lot}-{PartNum}-{Process1}"
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt1.Load(reader)
        End Using
        lst.Add(dt1)
        cmd.Parameters("@HELPER").Value = $"{Lot}-{PartNum}-{Process2}"
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt2.Load(reader)
        End Using
        lst.Add(dt2)
        cmd.Parameters("@HELPER").Value = $"{Lot}-{PartNum}-{Process3}"
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt3.Load(reader)
        End Using
        lst.Add(dt3)
        cmd.Parameters("@HELPER").Value = $"{Lot}-{PartNum}-{Process4}"
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt4.Load(reader)
        End Using
        lst.Add(dt4)
        cmd.Parameters("@HELPER").Value = $"{Lot}-{PartNum}-{Process5}"
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt5.Load(reader)
        End Using
        lst.Add(dt5)
    End Using
    Return lst
End Function
```

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question with your db schema?

Comment: Could you provide the code used to gather the data from access? I've experiences performance issues when populating datasets/datatables with large amounts of rows, depending on how they were populated.

Comment: I've updated the post. thanks.